# Create order programatically without billing and shipping address

Tags: magento2, sales-order, shipping-address, billing-address

I have a couple of virtual products in my Magento 2 website, I’d like to create the order programmatically without inputting shipping and billing address, is that even possible?

Comment: Can you please clarify more what do you mean by Programatically ?because magento already provides what you're asking.

Comment: [Virtual products are used for non-tangible products such as services, subscriptions, and warranties]

Shipping Options do not appear during checkout unless there is a tangible product in the cart.

Comment: @AdityaShah how about billing address?

Comment: @TinyDancer You might use generic billing & shipping address